# UpdateSingleSalesforceObject not executing

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a cloudpage in place with two buttons. Upon clicking on one of these buttons, I am redirecting a customer towards another cloudpage, where I am displaying a thank you messsage. Upon the redirect I would like to set a boolean field on a custom service cloud object to false. This is the code I currently have:

```
%%[
/* Set BooleanValue on InterestData Record PEDM03 to False */
SET @contact_id = _subscriberKey
SET @pedm03_id  = Lookup("CB_InterestData__c_Salesforce_1", "Id", "CB_ContactID__c", @contact_id)

IF not Empty(@pedm03_id) THEN
    @update_PEDM03 = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("CB_InterestData__c", @pedm03_id, "CB_BooleanValue__c", "False")
ENDIF
]%%
```

I am retrieving the record ID from a marketing cloud synchronized DE. For debugging purposes I added a v() function to make sure the ID is populated. I can confirm that the value is the correct value and it's returned from the Lookup.

Upon reading the documentation I noticed that the UpdateSingleSalesforceObject function requires string arguments. I have tried a boolean input but this resulted in a 500 error on the page. I have used the following piece of code for debugging:

```
%%[ IF @update_PEDM03 == 1 THEN ]%%
pedm03_id value: %%=v(@pedm03_id)=%%
UpdateSingleSalesforceObject value: succes / 1
%%[ ELSEIF @update_PEDM03 == 0 THEN ]%%
pedm03_id value: %%=v(@pedm03_id)=%%
UpdateSingleSalesforceObject value: failed / 0
%%[ ELSE ]%%
pedm03_id value: %%=v(@pedm03_id)=%%
UpdateSingleSalesforceObject value: null
%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

It's currently execuiting the ELSE clause, which means UpdateSingleSalesforceObject is neiter 1 or 0. Can anyone help me troubleshoot the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are missing 'SET' in the first block of code. SET @update_PEDM03

Comment: Thanks @Swati. It's resolved now :)